# How to implement Areas using ASP.NET CORE (API)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-mvc-areas

I create the structure:

```
+Areas
   +Link (Area)
       +Controllers
           PaymentController.cs
```

My controller:

```
[Area("link")]
[Route("link/[controller]")]
public class PaymentController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok("Test");
    }
}
```

In Startup.cs I set:

```
routes.MapRoute("areaRoute", "{area:exists}/{controller}/{action=Get}/{id?}");
```

But when I try to access:

http://localhost:5000/Link/Pagamento/get
or

http://localhost:5000/api/Link/Pagamento/get

both calls return 404.

Whats is wrong?

---

**[Solution]**

The `[Route("link/[controller]")]` was the problem
I removed and all works fine.

Comment: The link is an Area

Comment: I tryed, not worked.